# How can I rename the default constructor provided by Perl's Moose module?

Tags: perl, constructor, moose

Is there a way to rename the default constructor provided by Moose to something other than "new"?

I want to do this to make a script more user friendly when it would make more sense to name the constructor something different (like "make_thing" for example)

```
my $object = Class->make_thing();
```

How can I make this happen?

---

***Let me give you an example of how this might be more user friendly...***

Say I'm building a module that handles CVS repository information and the module is called "CVS".  I could either create an instance of a repository with

`$repository = CVS->new()`

or if I could change the name of the constructor I could call it something like

`$repository = CVS->get_repository()`

which would make more logical sense the user.

Comment: Being Perl, I'm sure you can, but using a different name than the standard name used by lots of Moose developers and the Moose documentation, doesn't *sound* very user-friendly...

Comment: I added an example where I think changing the name of the constructor might make logical sense from a user perspective.

Comment: The most user-friendly thing you can do is follow the standard conventions of perl, where `new` is the name of the constructor.

Comment: You can write `*CVS::make_thing = \&CVS::new` to create an *alias* for the method, but I disagree very much that an alternative name may be easier to understand. It is not just Perl, but the vast majority of programming languages use `new` for the constructor class method, as well as `self` or `this` for the current context object. I think you will confuse people rather than clarify things for them by deviating from this convention

Comment: Moose best practices: [Never override `new`](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/Moose/lib/Moose/Manual/BestPractices.pod#Never-override-new)

Comment: Why are you calling your class "CVS" if the *"constructor"* creates a "repository"? Call it `CVS::Repository` and then `CVS::Repository->new()` makes the same sense. However you may want a simple interface to your entire library and "CVS" is the facade you chose and you want to make `CVS` a data pool and factory. Then `get_repository` calls 'CVS::Repository->new()`.

Comment: I disagree with all the people saying "don't provide other constructors". For example [DateTime](https://metacpan.org/pod/DateTime#Constructors) provides a raft of constructors

Comment: @glennjackman, the question is not how to "override" `new`.  It's simply how to rename `new`.  renaming and overriding are two different things.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sometimes it makes sense to have alternative constructors.  For instance, if you look at [Net::Works::Network](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::Works::Network), it has `new_from_string` and `new_from_integer` methods.  I'd stay away from using something other than `new` unless you have a very good reason.  Having said that, you could just add a convenience method if you think it's more helpful to the user.

```
sub get_repository {
    my $class = shift;
    return $class->new( @_ );
}
```

Comment: It's not exactly "renaming" `new`, but this approach would be better I guess since it still preserves `new` as a valid constructor which will allow people to use it if they would like to.